# Running two node.JS servers simultaneously with different versions on a windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm

Looking for something like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for windows, to be exact the nvm run command:

```
nvm run 4.2.5 app.js
nvm run 5.0.0 index.js
```

**So I could have two servers running different node.JS versions at the same time.**

Searching for libraries I came across nvmw, which seem to have a similar approach but it is not being actively developed nor supported.

(it also has some open bugs which are deal breakers for my use case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

For Windows, these are your options:

1. use real `nvm`, but on BashOnWindows/Windows Subsystem for Linux
2. use an alternative: `nvm-windows`, `nvs`, `ps-nvm`, to name a few

Comment: Your first suggestion regarding bash sounds awesome I will try it - thanks!